# How to drill down to a bad record in a large data set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m looking for a more efficient way to drill down to one record in large data sets. Every once in a while I have to find a record that made it past the cleaning process and has some junk data in one of the fields. Currently I wind up dropping back to a cursor, that’s wildly inefficient, to loop over the data set. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(
PK INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
SomeVal VARCHAR(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #t(SomeVal)
VALUES('1.2'),('3.4'),('5.6'),('7.8 Junk.....')


DECLARE x CURSOR FOR SELECT PK, SomeVal FROM #t
DECLARE @y INT
DECLARE @z VARCHAR(50)

OPEN x
FETCH NEXT FROM x INTO @y, @z

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT CAST(@z AS MONEY) --Create the error
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT('The Primary key is: ' + CAST(@y AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' and the offending value is: ' + @z) --Catch the records primary key and the value that causes the error
        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM x INTO @y, @z
    END

CLOSE x
DEALLOCATE x
DROP TABLE #t
```

Does anyone have a pro tip that makes this faster? I know that cursors are bad news most of the time but I had to come with something in pinch...I want to be better prepared the next time it comes up.

Comment: Just use IsNumeric, it returns 0 if the value is not numeric so you can simply filter the result set where is numeric is 0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql e.g. `select * from table where isnumeric(offending_column) = 0`

Comment: @Charleh I looked at the IsNumeric function but what I don't like about it is that the ms docs say that it will return 1 if there is a dollar sign in the field. That may not cause an issue in most cases but it will in mine. Great solution though.

Comment: @Charleh [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Comment: @BillRuhl Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers, e.g. `Try_Convert()` arrived with SQL Server 2012. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @HABO who doesn't love a bit of fuzzy input "correction" though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql)/[TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) will return NULL on a fail and are designed specifically for that scenario.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(@z AS MONEY)
```

Comment: Thanks..this is why I ask the pros...I never saw the TRY_CAST function...way better!

Comment: Yeah, I've said for years that try_cast/try_convert are worth switching from 2008R2 to 2012 by themselves!